# How to handle large amounts of scheduled tasks on a web server?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, lamp

I'm developing a website (using a LAMP stack) which must handle many user-made scheduling tasks. It works as following: an user creates an event and sets a date, and others users (as many as 63)  may join. A few hours before the set date, the system must email each user subscribed to that event. And that's it.

However, I have never handled scheduling, and the only tools I know (poorly) are cron and at. My plan is to create an at job for each event, which will call a script that gets all subscribers emails and mails them.

My question is: is my plan/design good? Is it scalable? Are there better options that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would consider a proper framework that uses an application server (and not a simple webserver), [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) has a [task scheduling layer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) that's simple to use.  Scheduling jobs on the server really requires more than what a simple LAMP install can do, but I haven't used PHP in a while so maybe there's an equivalent.

[Here's](http://www.web4j.com/Criticisms_Drawbacks_Pitfalls_Spring_Rails_PHP.jsp) an article that compares some of your options.

Comment: That seems qui more complex than what I had in mind... but also seems like a powerful solution. I think it will be worth to spend some extra time learning about app servers than half-assing the scheduled tasks. The links you provided were very useful! Tanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why a separate cron job for each event? I've done something similar thing for a newsletter with a cron job just running  once per hour and if there are any newsletters to be sent it just handles them. In your case you'd have a script that runs once every hour  and gets a list of users for events that happen in the desired time interval since.

It will work. As far as scalability, at the minimum make sure that the script runs in it's own process so it doesn't bog down the server unnecessarily.

Create a php-cli script perhaps?

I'm doing most of my work in Rails nowadays, and there's a wealth of background processing libraries one of them is Resque it uses the redis server to keep track of the jobs
I found a PHP clone https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque

Might be overkill for your use case, but give it a shot perhaps

Comment: For a newsletter, that seems like a reasonable solution. However, I don't know if cron jobs would be good for my use case since it has a date defined by a user, who can single out a minute. Running the cron job every minute would be bad performance wise, while running in larger time frames could not be as precise as I want. I could limit the minutes in the event creation to multiples of 15 or 30 (it would be easier to handle), but I'd rather try something else.

Comment: It'll be hard to do real time responsiveness with cron. it would be reasonable to limit the minimum time to something like 15 minutes so that you don't over do it. My point is to have a single out of process sender that doesn't impact the webserver. Even if you use a library such as rescue it may be too much activity if you run every minute.