# Scheduled task for large data processing

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

I have an application on php which has large number of Scheduled database which need to be processed and need to scan for new task for every munities to process. So I think a basic “cornjob” type option not better for me because it will slow down my application I think. What’s the solution for me? How application like wordpress handles such Scheduled job with vast database? I want to proper solution will be not slowdown my application and can handle large database like 20000 raw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question explained well on another threat [Click here to visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638323/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-scheduled-tasks-on-a-web-server) Before post question please research most of the time its already answered